# How to print WORKING_DIRECTORY in CMake?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, ctest

I have this line in my CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_test(NAME ${PROJECT_NAME} COMMAND ${PROJECT_NAME} WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

The problem is that `WORKING_DIRECTORY` does not seem to be set correctly.

```
message("Futurama ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}")
```

It shows that `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR` is what I expect, but when I run my generated VS projects, the work folder is `$(ProjectDir)`, and that is wrong since I do the build in a separate folder.

Is it possible that setting of `WORKING_DIRECTORY`  is broken for the Visual Studio generator?

If not, how can I print the status of `WORKING_DIRECTORY`  after `add_test`?

Comment: It looks like you set the working directory to the *project source directory*, which is not the build directory. This seems to be correctly set in Visual Studio with `$(ProjectDir)`, so I'm not sure what the issue is. What is the **desired** behavior?

Comment: @squareskittles $(ProjectDir) is in my build/a/b/c/  folder... I would like to set CWD for test to be same folder as the source folder. 
build is totall different folder from the source folder.

(build is the name of my build folder, I do not do in source build)

Comment: "how can I print the status of WORKING_DIRECTORY after add_test?" - You may read [WORKING_DIRECTORY](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_test/WORKING_DIRECTORY.html) property of the test. E.g. by `get_test_property(<test-name> WORIKING_DIRECTORY test_dir)` and printing a value of the `test_dir` variable.

Comment: @Tsyvarev 
This:

add_test(NAME ${PROJECT_NAME} COMMAND ${PROJECT_NAME} WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
get_test_property(${PROJECT_NAME} WORIKING_DIRECTORY test_dir)
message("Futurama2 ${test_dir}")

prints:

1>  Futurama D:/GIT/... (correct path to source)

1>  Futurama2 NOTFOUND

Comment: You misspelled `WORKING_DIRECTORY`.

Comment: @squareskittles dont blindly c/p from SO kids :) . Thank you for noticing... Now it shows that value is set correctly... I guess that problem is that VS generator is buggy/limited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you may verify that the `WORKING_DIRECTORY` is set properly.

**Programmatically (as commented):**

```
get_test_property(${PROJECT_NAME} WORKING_DIRECTORY test_dir)
message("My test's working directory: ${test_dir}")
```

**Inspection:**

Navigate to the `CTestTestfile.cmake` file in your build folder, and open it in a text editor. You can see in the commands here that the `WORKING_DIRECTORY` property is being properly set.

---

However, the `$(ProjectDir)` listed for **Working Directory** of the `RUN_TESTS` Visual Studio project is pointing to a folder in your build directory; this is a **Debugging** property and isn't actually used when running the CTest tests. This is used when Visual Studio is debugging an executable. Because the `RUN_TESTS` project cannot actually be debugged (the CTest tests are actually run as a post-build event), this **Working Directory** property doesn't apply to your situation.

Comment: yes, you are correct, in the end I ended up copying the test files to where binary is...
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different ...